# Python on Mac Web Server

Tags: python, macos

Currently, I have PHP and Perl running fine on my machine. What I want to do is run Python websites (Development). I have Python installed. I looked online for ways of doing this, but unfortunately can't run my hello.py file that prints "Hello World" on the screen. (Screen shows the source code, and I have #!/usr/bin/python on the top of the file). I tried to modify my httpd.conf file but it crashed the server and nothing would load. (I followed this tutorial: [How do you set up Python scripts to work in Apache 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102/how-do-you-set-up-python-scripts-to-work-in-apache-2-0)) 
What are the things I need to do/change to successfully run Python website on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get a simple "Hello, World!" script running is to enable cgi handling of the scripts. Basically you would modify your httpd.conf and search for an "AddHandler cgi-script" line. Add .py to the end of it so that it looks something like this:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
```

Also, you may need to enable cgi handling for that filetype in that folder.

```
<Location /some/path/*.py>
Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

Finally, make sure you're serving the right content type and headers and out comes your content:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello world!</html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), your Python app can self-host for development.

Comment: What if i dont want to use a franework? (Not yet) i just wanna get to run "hello world" in my browser in python. The rest will come.

Comment: Please look at Flask before you make something *more* complicated by yourself ;)

Comment: I completely disagree. Running a "hello, world" should be step 1. Installing a whole framework is beyond what he's asking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what on which point you're disagreeing. "If you use a framework" is an objective statement. I recommend a microframework to handle routing because CGI development is pretty antiquated. It so happens that the recommended framework is self-hosting, which means you can have a running "Hello World" in simple steps clearly detailed on the Flask homepage. As far as "What I want to do is run Python websites (Development)", `mod_cgi` is probably the wrong tool for the job. If the question were "How do I run a Python cli script via a URL?", just maybe `mod_cgi` might be an easier choice.