# User-Signup Form - Getting Error Messages to Display On Wrong Entry Only

Tags: python, forms, function, class, post

Please take a look at this screenshot of the web app I'm running locally:

[image]

As you might imagine, what I'm trying to do is create error messages when the user messes up. There are five parameters for triggering error messages:

1. The user doesn't enter a username
2. The username is invalid -- contains a space character, it isn't between 3 and 20 characters, and/or it contains characters that aren't a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9
3. The password is invalid -- it isn't between 3 and 20 characters
4. The passwords don't match -- 'Verify Password' is not the same as 'Password'
5. The email is invalid -- must match `(r'^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\]+$')`, meaning a bunch of characters, an @ sign, a bunch of characters, a period, and a bunch of characters.

As you can see, my code is currently displaying the error messages when the page is loaded, instead of after the user hits 'submit'.

I've been unable to host this web app on a website for reasons listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010384/running-python-on-server-with-mac) (my hosting service, HostGator, doesn't support WebApp2, and I wasn't able to upload the repository to Google Cloud).

To help, you'll probably have to test these files locally (maybe via Google App Engine). Here's a link to my GitHub repository and the code for the file, main.py:

https://github.com/user3546086/user-signup

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
# implied.

# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
import webapp2
import cgi

def Build_Page(textarea_content):

form = """
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>{0}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></label>
    </td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>{1}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Password: <input type="text" name="password"/></label>
    </td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td> 
    <label>{2}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Verify Password: <input type="text" name="verify_password"/>
    </label>
    </td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>{3}</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Email (optional): <input type="text" name="email"/></label>
    </td></tr>

    </table>
    """
    submit = "<input type = 'submit'/>"
    form2 = ("<form method='post'>" 
        + form + submit + "</form>").format("Please enter a valid
    username", "Please enter a valid password", "Your passwords must
    match", "Please enter a valid email")

    header = "<h1>User Signup</h1>" 

    return header + form2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    content = Build_Page("")
    self.response.write(content)

    def post(self):
    # look inside the request to figure out what the user typed
    username = self.request.get("username")
    password = self.request.get("password")
    verify_password = self.request.get("verify_password")
    email = self.request.get("email")
    # if the user typed nothing at all, redirect
    if (not username) or (username.strip() == ""):
        error = "Please enter a valid username."
        self.response.write(error)
        self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))

    if (not password) or (username.strip() == ""):
        error = "Please enter a username."
        self.response.write(error)
        self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))

    """if (not username) or (username.strip() == ""):
        error = "Please enter a username."
        self.response.write(error)
        self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))

    if (not username) or (username.strip() == ""):
        error = "Please enter a username."
        self.response.write(error)
        self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))"""

    #              self.write.form2    
    #message = self.request.get("message") 
    # hello</textarea>hello
    #rotation = int(self.request.get("rotation")) 
    # 0 
    #encrypted_message = caesar.encrypt(message, rotation) 
    # hello</textarea>hello
    #escaped_message = cgi.escape(encrypted_message) 
    # hello&lt;/textarea&gt;hello
    #content = build_page(escaped_message)
    #self.response.write(content)

    #originalform = form.format("","","","","","")
    #page footer

    #class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #    """ Handles requests coming in to '/add'
    #        e.g. www.user-signup.com/add
    #    """
    #    def get(self):

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    #('/', TestHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Also here's the video with the so called solution, except I'm not allowed to use a framework like he uses for this project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHtUNPslte4

I tried to create a 'params' variable like he did in the post function within my MainHandler class, but nothing is happening. So my MainHandler class now looks like this:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    content = Build_Page("")
    self.response.write(content)

def post(self):
    # look inside the request to figure out what the user typed
    have_error = False
    username = self.request.get("username")
    password = self.request.get("password")
    verify_password = self.request.get("verify_password")
    email = self.request.get("email")

    params = dict(username = username,
                  email = email)

    # if the user typed nothing at all, redirect
    if (not username) or (username.strip() == ""):
        #error = "Please enter a valid username."
        #self.response.write(error)
        #self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))
        params['error_username'] = "Please enter a valid username."
        have_error = True

    if (not password) or (password.strip() == ""):
        #error = "Please enter a username."
        #self.response.write(error)
        #self.redirect("/?error=" + cgi.escape(error, quote=True))
        params['error_password'] = "Please enter a valid password."
        have_error = True

    if have_error:
        self.render('signup-form.html', **params)
    else:
        self.redirect('/unit2/welcome?username=' + username)
```

And everything else in the code still looks the same. Not sure why the error messages aren't showing up when the params aren't met like I thought I had specified. Please help if you can, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, your error messages are displaying to the left of the text-boxes because that's where you put them in your table. When you do string substitution, you want your messages to display to the right of the labels when the user enters them incorrectly. So your table should look like this:

```
import webapp2
import cgi
import re

form = """
<h1>User Signup</h1>
<form method = "post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></label>
</td>
<td>
<label style="color:red">{username_message}</label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Password: <input type="text" name="password"/></label>
<td>
<label style="color:red">{password_message}</label>
</td>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Verify Password: <input type="text" name="verify_password"/>
</label>

<td> 
<label style="color:red">{password_match_message}</label>
</td>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Email (optional): <input type="text" name="email"/></label>
<td>
<label style="color:red">{email_message}</label>
</td>
</td></tr>

</table>
<input type = 'submit'/>
</form>
"""
```

You can see that I created variable names for the different error messages, and created a form with method = "post" outside of the table. Turning it into a post form allows us to use the post function within the MainHandler class later. That is how you'll get the information the user typed and compare it against the `valid_username`, `valid_password`, and `valid_email` functions (these functions were created by the teacher in the linked video):

```
USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
def valid_username(username):
    return username and USER_RE.match(username)

PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$")
def valid_password(password):
    return password and PASS_RE.match(password)

def equal_password(verify_password, password):
    if password == verify_password:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r'^[\S]+@[\S\+\.[\S]+$')
def valid_email(email):
    return not email or EMAIL_RE.match(email)
```

Also in the MainHandler class, you want to create a helper function, which has parameters that initially set the variables to empty strings.

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def helper(self, user_message="", user_password="", match_password="",
user_email=""):
#string substitution
   self.response.write(form.format(username_message= user_message, 
                              password_message= user_password, 
                              password_match_message= match_password,
                              email_message= user_email
                              ))
```

See these links for more information about string substitution (that's what '.format' is doing):

https://pyformat.info/

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Next use the get method to get the information entered into the form. Use the helper function that you created to get the information entered for the variables.

```
def get(self):
    self.helper()
```

Now in the post method, you'll look inside the request to figure out what the user typed.

```
def post(self):
    # look inside the request to figure out what the user typed
    username = self.request.get("username")
    password = self.request.get("password")
    verify_password = self.request.get("verify_password")
    email = self.request.get("email")

    params = dict(username = username,
                  email = email)
```

Then you'll create your if statements to test whether or not the requirements have been met. First you'll want to create a scenario where the user meets all of the requirements. You'll want to redirect them to a welcome page in that case.

```
#if valid_username(username) == "" or ! valid_username
    user_message="" 
    user_password=""
    match_password=""
    user_email=""
    if valid_username(username) and valid_password(password) and equal_password(password, verify_password) and valid_email(email):
        self.redirect('/welcome?username=' + username)
```

Then you'll set up if statements for when the user doesn't meet the requirements:

```
    if not valid_username(username):
        user_message="Username not valid"
    if not valid_password(password):
        user_password="Password not valid"
    if not equal_password(password, verify_password):
        match_password="Passwords must match"
    if email is not "" and not valid_email(email):
        user_email="Please enter a valid email"           

    self.response.write(form.format(username_message= user_message, 
                              password_message= user_password, 
                              password_match_message= match_password,
                              email_message= user_email
                              ))
```

If the user enters the correct information, you'll want to redirect to a welcome page. Create a new class `Welcome` that defines what to write by getting what the user entered as their username.

```
class Welcome(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        if valid_username(username):
             self.response.write(welcome.format(username = username))

#html for welcome page            
welcome = """
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
    User Signup
    </title>
</head>

<body>
#string substitution for username 
<h2>Welcome, {username}!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Lastly, create the parameters for your home page and welcome page:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainHandler),
('/welcome', Welcome)
], debug=True)
```