# Easiest way to run python script from Apache

Tags: python, apache

I have spent ages trying to figure this out. I'm basically trying to develop a website where I have to execute a python script when the users clicks a specific button. After researching on Stack Overflow and Google, I need to configure Apache to be able to run CGI scripts. I have seen numerous examples of software that can accomplish this, such as [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). The problem is that I get extremely confused with the instructions for these softwares, especially for [mod_wsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). I don't understand the instructions at all, and I can't install the software and get anything to work.

If anyone has a very easy method for executing python scripts in Apache, I would greatly appreciate. If anyone would like to explain how to use mod_wsgi, I would greatly appreciate that as well, because as of right now I have no idea how to use it and the installation instructions are confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102/how-do-you-set-up-python-scripts-to-work-in-apache-2-0

Answer (score 3):

One way, not so easy but simple in some way, is to use CGI, as you said.
You can find more information on [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html) and [Python CGI module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cgi.html).

But, basically, you have to set your server to run cgi sripts. This is done by editing httpd.conf or a .htaccess file:
For the first option, add or uncomment the follow:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/ # update the second location according to your configuration. It has to be a place where apache is allow to use, otherwise see apache documentation for setting another directory.
```

Then, you just need to add your python script in the directory that you set above.

Note that the output from your script must be preceded by a mime-type header, as Apache documentation says.

So, a hello world script could be named hello.py and its content could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print('Content-type: text/html') # the mime-type header.
print() # header must be separated from body by 1 empty line.
print('Hello world')
```

Than, you can call your scrit from a browser:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py
```

Note that Python has some goodies inside its cgi realted builtin modules. The cgi module will give you a way to handle forms, and cgitb will give you a helpful (but not perfect) way to debug your script. For more on that, read the documentation again.

Finally, using cgi directly to run python scripts gives you a raw way to work with http requests. There is a lot of already done frameworks, like flask and django, that gives you more power easily. You could check that.

Comment: i dont have a httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2

Comment: @MIHAEL Depends of your Linux distribution. /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/httpd/httpd.conf.